# How to discover hard drive's S\N in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

A while back I bought 3 identical hard drives to create a RAID. After lots of trouble I decided to let go of my geeky dream and just use the without RAID.

Now one of the hard drives is faulty and is not recognized by Windows. I would like to disconnect it, but I don't know which of the three is the problematic one. Of course I could always run a trial and error, but just for the sake of knowledge I was wondering...

**Is there a way to know the serial number (not model number) of a hard drive win Windows?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest Way:

Like Jason404 I could of sworn you could do this in Device Manager or System Information, but I can't find it anywhere.

I would say a tool I like using is [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy/download/portable).

One click and you can easily find out the information!
[image]

Comment: Just as a note you might want to edit your link - clicking on it automatically starts downloading a file; not everyone likes to be linked to an automatic download.  I agree that the program is useful and piriform generally writes great software.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose some information utility should do the trick. Like this:

http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find any way of doing this within Windows, although I thought you could in Device Manager.  An easy way would be to use some SMART monitoring software.  [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) is a good one, which needs no installation.